# WPF toolkit charting Lineseries styling

Tags: charts, wpftoolkit

Is it possible to change the thickness of the LineSeries? 
Is it possible to show LineSeries as dashed lines?
I have othe question about AreaSeries, no matter what all my Area Series are drawing from x-Axis. What I want is that I can draw let say a area for these four point (2,2), (2,6), (8,6), (8,2).
How can I manage it?

Answer (score 5):

For setting the thickness and dashed line style of a LineSeries, use a Style like the one shown here:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DashedPolyLine" TargetType="{x:Type Polyline}">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="4, 2" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
.
.
.
<charting:LineSeries
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
    IndependentValuePath="myIndValue"
    DependentValuePath="myDepValue"
    PolylineStyle="{StaticResource DashedPolyLine}"
</charting:LineSeries>
```

Comment: For setting line thickness, use `StrokeThickness` instead od `Width`